# Что такое телескопический конструктор

Tags: java, конструктор

Где-то видел такое словосочетание, как телескопический конструктор. Когда искал поисковик подсовывал только информацию про паттерн Строитель. Но в статья это словосочетание не фигурировало.

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/design-patterns-simple-words-1/  - со слов Давайте я покажу на примере, что такое «Телескопический конструктор». Буквально чуть-чуть

Comment: Для тех, кто не может открыть ссылку и найти - телескопический коструктор, это конструктор у которого очень много параметров (больше десятка точно)

Answer (score 1):

Это конструктор, вариации которого всё больше разрастаются по мере потребностей пользователя, т.е. растёт число перегрузок с различными видами и числом аргументов.

Практика не очень удачная, поэтому такой конструктор считается антипаттерном.

Его более лучшая альтернатива - паттерн *Строитель*.